# Send a mail in android studio

Tags: java, email, android-studio

I have this code which is working completely error free, but not as per the expected output. When it runs it should provide a choice on how to send a mail, but it provides me with only Bluetooth and  messenger not email.

```
  protected void sendEmail() {
  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Sending mail",          Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  String[] TO = {"xyz@gmail.com"};
  String[] CC = {"abc@gmail.com"};
  Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
  emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
  emailIntent.setType("text/plain");


  emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, TO);
  emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, CC);
  emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
  emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Email message :");

  try {
     startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
     finish();
     Log.i("Finished sending email...", "");
  } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
     Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, 
     "There is no email client installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

### use this

---

```
protected void sendEmail() {
       
       Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse("mailto:aaaaaa@gmail.com"));
       emailIntent.putExtra("subject", "Feedback");
       emailIntent.putExtra("body", "");
       startActivity(emailIntent);

      
    }
```